# JavaScript's regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to parse the following text:

> This is one of the [name]John's[/name]
>   first tutorials.

or

> Please invite [name]Steven[/name] to
>   the meeting.

What I need is to do a regexp in Javascript to get the name.
Doing `var str = body.match(/[name](.*?)[\/name]/g);` works, but how do I get just the inside of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the "exec" method of a regular expression to get the matching groups as an array:

```
var getName = function(str) {
  var m = /\[name\](.*?)\[\/name\]/.exec(str);
  return (m) ? m[1] : null;
}

var john = getName("This is one of [name]John's[/name] first tutorials.");
john // => "John's"
var steve = getName("Please invite [name]Steven[/name] to the meeting.");
steve // => "Steven"
```

This could be easily extended to find all occurrences of names by using a global RegExp:

```
var getAllNames = function(str) {
  var regex = /\[name\](.*?)\[\/name\]/g
    , names = []
    , match;
  while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    names.push(match[1]);
  }
  return names;
}

var names = getAllNames("Hi [name]John[/name], and [name]Steve[/name]!");
names; // => ["John", "Steve"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to access the matched groups. For an explanation, see here:
[How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in your regexp, you have to escape brackets: `\[name\]`. Just writing `[name]` in regexp means that there should be either 'n' or 'a' or 'm' or 'e'. And in your case you just want to tell that you look for something started with '[name]' as string

altogether:

```
/\[name\](.*?)\[\/name\]/g.exec('Please invite [name]Steven[/name] to the meeting.');
console.info( RegExp.$1 ) // "Steven"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp.$1`, `RegExp.$2`, all the way to `RegExp.$9` to access the part(s) inside the parenthesis. In this case, `RegExp.$1` would contain the text in between the `[name]` and `[/name]`.

Comment: No, it is necessary. If he has multiple `[name]...[/name]` tags, doing `(.*)` will do a greedy match and match everything between the first `[name]` and last `[/name]`.